# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable using list and string conversion

Tags: python, string, list

With the code I have tried so far,  I get the error as described below:

```
   L=[1,2,3,4]
   s1 = ":".join(str(x)for x in L)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-9a830429dd90> in <module>
      1 L=[1,2,3,4]
----> 2 s1 = ":".join(str(x)for x in L)
      3 
      4 

<ipython-input-128-9a830429dd90> in <genexpr>(.0)
      1 L=[1,2,3,4]
----> 2 s1 = ":".join(str(x)for x in L)
      3 
      4 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Even if try this code:

```
for x in L :
    print(str(x))
s1 = ":".join(str(x)for x in L)

I get below error
----> 3     print(str(x))
      4 s1 = ":".join(str(x)for x in L)
      5 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm running this code in Jupyter notebook Python version : 3.7.1

Comment: You probably have `str = ...` somewhere in your code, hiding the bultin type/function. If this is an interactive shell, try `del str` to un-hide the builtin.

Comment: Great del str worked. Can you please explain what was causing the issue ? I did not have str = assignment in any of the cells.

Comment: You sure about that? Maybe you had `str` as a `for` loop variable or a "leaky" list comprehension with `[... for str in ...]` somewhere?